# Can a tablet with USB-C work with a USB-C dock?

Tags: android, tablet, usb-c, docking-stations

I'm thinking about buying a tablet and I'm wondering if I can plug in a tablet with USB-C to a USB-C dock, so my monitor can project my tablet’s screen. Its like plugging in a laptop to a dock and having the laptop screen bigger on my monitor except its an android tablet.

Note:
I don't want to fry my tablet or do anything that would cause problems with its hardware.

Answer (score 1):

As always with USB-C, it depends.

If your tablet supports Thunderbolt 3 or 4, totally yes. If it doesn't, probably not. If you don't know, try it. If your display recocnizes the tablet, it works, if not, probably no display for your tablet.

Since you will be buying a tablet, from unofficial sources I found out that the Samsung tab S7 does support display output over USB-C.